# How To Check If A Combination Of Foreign Keys Exists Multiple Times

Tags: c#, sql, key, combinations

So I have a database where there's the tables: Song, Artist and Producer. I want to check if an artist has produced more than 1 song at the same producer. The Song-Table already has the foreign keys of the artistID and producerID but how do I see in the song table if there's multiple combinations from those same ID's which would mean that the artist has producer more than 1 song at the same producer. This is what I have now, but I've been really stuck after this:

```
query = "select Name from Artist where 1 < (Select count(*) from Song where....";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a basic aggregation:

```
select artistId, producerId, count(*) as numsongs
from song
group by artistId, producerId
having count(*) > 1;
```

You can join back to `Artist` and/or `Producer` if you want names instead of ids.